# Decimals Not Storing Even With Precision and Scale Set - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I find that the decimal results of my calculations come to 0.00 even with precision and scale set properly. Please see code below:

```
create table test
(
per decimal(10,2),
perler varchar(1)
)

insert into test(per,perler) values ('1.1','1')

UPDATE test set per = (1105018/2227130) where perler ='1'

select * from test
```

The above results in:

```
per   |  perler
0.00  |  1
```

Comment: Seems right. You're doing integer division. Add a .0 to one of those values and see what happens.

Comment: @Tieson T. Wow..Now it works. Is it that I have to do a cast?

Comment: `UPDATE test set per = (1105018/2227130.0) where perler ='1'` should work.

Comment: @J.Smith You should probably read up on what integer division is.

Comment: @TiesonT. Just needed to cast it:  CAST(1105018 AS float) / CAST(2227130 AS float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does *integer* devision.  You need to add a decimal point to make this work:

```
UPDATE test 
    SET per = (1105018.0/2227130) 
    WHERE perler = '1';
```

If you want to be pedantic about the types, you can explicitly cast to decimal:

```
UPDATE test 
    SET per = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 20), 1105018) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 2227130) 
    WHERE perler = '1';
```

However, this is not generally necessary.